# RegularExpressionAttribute fails validating right data

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, validationattribute

I have a regular expression that works great when I try it:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("universal",@"^[A-Za-z0-9 ._’&-/s]{0,100}$")
true

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("universal £$%$£%",@"^[A-Za-z0-9 ._’&-/s]{0,100}$")
false
```

But when I use it as a validation filter:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9 ._’&-/s]{0,100}$", ErrorMessage = "The parameter is not valid")]
```

It works in the client side, but it does not work on the server side. For example when I pass the word "universal" the `ModelState` contains an error regarding the field marked with that regex validator.

This attribute is the only validation rule applied to that field, what may be the problem?

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with .NETs regex implementation, but `&-/s` looks a bit odd. Do you mean the ascii range from `&` to `/` and the the letter `s`? Or did you mean to include the special class `\s` and a literal `-`?

Comment: @NullOrEmpty:Hi ,i have the same problem have you found the solution?